# PySide2 crash when creating QApplication subclass within main()

Tags: python, qt, python-3.8, pyside2, qapplication

I have a PySide2 (5.15.2.1) app on macOS 10.14.6 that works fine under Python 3.6 and 3.7 but crashes under Python 3.8. The minimal crashing example (seg fault 11) is:

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt

class AppSubclass(QtWidgets.QApplication):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidgets.QApplication.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

def main():
    app = AppSubclass()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Strangely, removing the main function results in no crash:

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt

class AppSubclass(QtWidgets.QApplication):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidgets.QApplication.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

app = AppSubclass()
```

Is there something not right about how I'm subclassing QApplication?

Comment: Although the first script shouldn't segfault, it doesn't make much sense as a self-contained example, because `app` will be immediately garbage-collected after `main()` returns. In the other example, `app` will remain alive for the entire lifetime of the script. In general, python's garbage-collector does not guarantee any particular order when deleting objects, and this can sometimes cause problems if Qt tries to delete the underlying C++ parts in a different order. The usual fix is to re-structure the code so as to ensure the QApplication is the last object deleted (e.g. make `app` global).

Comment: Thanks @ekhumoro, that was a really helpful tip. It turns out to be a bug in PySide, but it's indeed related to garbage-collection as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

This turns out to likely be a bug in PySide, which has been solved. See https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-1447